# How to Redirect a Domain without Changing the URL in web.config file?

Tags: redirect, iis-7

I setup a redirect from one domain (https://test.mydomain.com) to another URL (http://testing.com/test/Login.aspx) and I want to keep the domain name in the address bar.  Basically, Redirect website visitors to another site, but do not show them the destination address, so they do not know about the redirection.

This is for a windows server 2008 r2, running iis 7.  I would like to amend the web.config file.

I expect the redirect to keep the original domain (https://test.mydomain.com).

Comment: You'll need to use URL Rewrite to do anything like this.  You need a Rewrite rule and not a Redirect.   Is the other site on the same server in the same AppPool?  If so, give a read thru https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module  if not, you'll need to do some Proxy type configuration.  Read: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing.  Note that both those links are for older versions of URL Rewrite & ARR, but still mostly apply.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I suggest that you use **URL Rewrite**.
First add the condition  to check whether URL is a `https` request, then add another condition to check the domain of URL. Add the rule below to your `web.config` file.

```
<rule name="test url rewrite">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="test.mydomain.com" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://testing.com/test/Login.aspx" />
</rule>
```